# Tree deletion with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, cascading-deletes

I'm struggling with a little problem and starting to arrive at the conclusion it's simply not possible.

I have a Table called Group. As with most of these systems Group has a ParentGroup and a Children collection. So the Table Group looks like this:

```
Group
  -ID (PK)
  -Name
  -ParentId (FK)
```

I did my mappings using FNH AutoMappings, but I had to override the defaults for this:

```
p.References(x => x.Parent)
    .Column("ParentId")
    .Cascade.All();
p.HasMany(x => x.Children)
    .KeyColumn("ParentId")
    .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Inverse();
```

Now, the general idea was to be able to delete a node and all of it's children to be deleted too by NH. So deleting the only root node should basically clear the whole table.

I tried first with `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan` but that works only for deletion of items from the Children collection, not deletion of the parent.

Next I tried `ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete` so the operation gets delegated to the Database through `on delete cascade`. But once I do that MSSql2008 does not allow me to create this constraint, failing with :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FKBA21C18E87B9D9F7' on table 'Group'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Well, and that's it for me. I guess I'll just loop through the children and delete them one by one, thus doing a N+1. If anyone has a suggestion on how do that more elegantly I'd be eager to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this and it worked.

```
    public class Node_Map : ClassMap<Node>
    {
        public Node_Map()
        {
            References(x => x.Parent, "IdCmsNodeParent");
            HasMany(x => x.Childs).AsBag()
                                  .Inverse()
                                  .Cascade.Delete()
                                  .KeyColumn("IdNodeParent");
        }
    }
```

But still, if NHibernate deletes it, you will get N+1. Only a right database constraint can delete it in one go.

If you want to do it efficiently in Sql server 2008 you should use recursive CTE.

Check:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx
- http://explainextended.com/2010/03/03/sql-server-deleting-with-self-referential-foreign-key/

Comment: But that way you don't use the same column for child and parent?
You end up with 2 FK columns: 

IdCmsNodeParent and IdNodeParent

It should be possible with only one.. 

Anyway, thanks for the link!

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry. IdCmsNodeParent should be IdNodeParent. I copy pasted my code and I wanted to delete word "Cms" because it did not have any information in it, but I forgot to delete it in the Reference method.